# How I get the image of a button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, button, uiimagepickercontroller

I set an image to a button using this code

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage


        btnImg1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        btnImg1.setImage(chosenImage, for: UIControlState.normal)

dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

now how I can get the selected image or I mean how to get the image of the button? I want the image to save it somewhare..
please help , thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for btnImg1.imageView?.image

Comment: In didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method when you set image to button object save its copy to another uiimage object and when you want to save image to somewhere just get the image from the uiiimage object.

Comment: you just store of image in global object of image also

Comment: First, you should add a target on the `touchUpInside` event on your `UIButton`, and then you can retrieve the image by `let image: UIImage = yourButton.image(for: .normal)!`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIButton contain ImageView, and when you assign image to UIImageView you can get is with its .image property

So for UIButton get ImageView and then Image

`button.imageView?.image` would give the image assigned to UIButton
If your button have different image for state you can also use .

```
    button.image(for: .normal or what ever state)
    button.imageView?.image
```

(Both will give same result if you set image with .normal)

[image]

@Rooh Al-mahaba You can access all property of UIImageView if you have UIButton object as UIButton contain an UIImageView to handle Image related part

Comment: @RoohAl-mahaba If my answer is what you were looking for, Mark it as Correct Answer

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use below code to get image back from Button:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "testImage")
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
    button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)

    //Get Image Back from Button
    let imageFromButton : UIImage = button.image(for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to get the image of the button:

```
let btnImag = btnImg1.image(for: .normal)
```